# Moving an image inside a canvas using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas where we can move a shape with arrow keys.

However, I want an image to move instead of a shape and I can't work it out.
Any help?

As of now, the image appears but I can't move it.
I tried many things on the internet but they didn't work. The id for the image is `image`.

This is my current code:

```
 car = {
  image : img,
  //jumping: true,
  x:180, // center of the canvas
  x_velocity:0,
  y: 160,
  y_velocity:0,
};  


controller = {

  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  down: false,
  keyListener:function(event) {

    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown")?true:false;

    switch(event.keyCode) {

      case 37:// left key
        controller.left = key_state;
      break;
      case 38:// up key
        controller.up = key_state;
      break;
      case 39:// right key
        controller.right = key_state;
      break;
      case 40: //down key
        controller.down = key_state;

    }

  }

};


loop = function() {

  if (controller.up) {
    car.image.y_velocity -= 0.5;

  }

  if (controller.left) {
    car.image.x_velocity -= 0.5;
  }

  if (controller.right) {
    car.image.x_velocity += 0.5;
  }

  if (controller.down) {
    car.image.y_velocity += 0.5;
  }

  car.image.x += car.image.x_velocity;
  car.image.y += car.image.y_velocity;
  car.image.x_velocity *= 0.9;// friction
  car.image.y_velocity *= 0.9;

  // if car.image is going off the left of the screen
  if (car.image.x < -32) {
    car.image.x = 1190;
// if car.image goes past right boundary
  } else if (car.image.x > 1190) {
    car.image.x = -32;
// if car.image goes past lower boundary
  } else if (car.image.y > 790) {
    car.image.y = 0;
// if car.image goes past upper boundary
  } else if (car.image.y < -32) {
    car.image.y = 790;
  }

  context.drawImage(car.image, car.x, car.y);

  // call update when the browser is ready to draw again
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

};

window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener) //press down and it moves
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);  //lift finger and it stops
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

This is the code when the shape was moving:

```
rectangle = {
  height:20,
  width:20,
  x:180, // location @ center of the canvas
  x_velocity:0,
  y: 160,
  y_velocity:0,

};

controller = {

  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  down: false,
  keyListener:function(event) {

    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown")?true:false;

    switch(event.keyCode) {

      case 37:// left key
        controller.left = key_state;
      break;
      case 38:// up key
        controller.up = key_state;
      break;
      case 39:// right key
        controller.right = key_state;
      break;
      case 40: //down key
        controller.down = key_state;

    }

  }

};

loop = function() {

  if (controller.up) {
    rectangle.y_velocity -= 0.5;
  }

  if (controller.left) {
    rectangle.x_velocity -= 0.5;
  }

  if (controller.right) {
    rectangle.x_velocity += 0.5;
  }

  if (controller.down) {
    rectangle.y_velocity += 0.5;
  }

  rectangle.x += rectangle.x_velocity;
  rectangle.y += rectangle.y_velocity;
  rectangle.x_velocity *= 0.9;// friction
  rectangle.y_velocity *= 0.9;// friction


  // if rectangle is going off the left of the screen
  if (rectangle.x < -32) {
    rectangle.x = 1190;
// if rectangle goes past right boundary
  } else if (rectangle.x > 1190) {
    rectangle.x = -32;
// if rectangle goes past lower boundary
  } else if (rectangle.y > 790) {
    rectangle.y = 0;
// if rectangle goes past upper boundary
  } else if (rectangle.y < -32) {
    rectangle.y = 790;
  }

  context.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 800);// x, y, width, height
  context.fillStyle = "white";// hex for red
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
  context.fill();

  // call update when the browser is ready to draw again
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

};

window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener) //press down and it moves
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);  //lift finger and it stops
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Comment: I don't know what code renders the arrow, but it could be the case that the image has a different `display` css property than the arrow? (by default the `<img>` element has `display: block;`) Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#Styling_with_CSS

Comment: What's it supposed to be then?

Comment: Try to inspect the arrow, and use the same attribute for the image.

Comment: It's not an arrow. It's a rectangle. And I can't inspect it since it's made in JavaScript.

Comment: Can't you right-click on it and select "inspect"? If you can't do that, I think you have a bigger issue there.

Comment: I can only inspect the canvas that way.

Comment: That's a good piece of information :)